# Disable button based onChange value in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can i tell onChange to set the disable button to true on the update button, if this.state.title is less than 3 characters, i made an attempt but it wont let me enter a value. It breaks the code pretty much. I want the update to be passed to redux.

here is what i have, disclaimer some code has been removed to be more relevant.

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {UpdatePost} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    button:{
        marginRight:'30px'
    }
}


class PostItem extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
        }
    }


    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }

    }
    render(){
        const {title, id, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                   <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                   {/* if else teneray operator */}
                   {isEditing ? (
                    //  need a way to disable update button if the value is less than 3 characters 
                       <Editable editField={myTitle ? myTitle : title} editChange={editChange}/>
                   ): (
                       <div>
                           {title}
                       </div>    
                   )}         
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography component="p">
                       {post_content}
                       <h5>
                           by: {username}</h5>
                       <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                   </Typography>
                   {!isEditing ? (
                       <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                           Edit
                       </Button>
                   ):(

                       // pass id, and myTitle which as we remember myTitle is the new value when updating the title
                    //  how would i set disabled to false if the value from editField is less than 3 charaters.
                        <Button 
                            disabled={this.state.title.length > 3 }
                            variant="outlined" 
                            onClick={this.onUpdate(id, myTitle)}>
                            Update
                        </Button>
                   )}
                   <Button
                       style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                       variant="outlined"
                       color="primary"
                       type="submit"
                       onClick={removePost(id)}>
                       Remove
                   </Button>
           </div>
       )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    disabled: state.post.disabled
})


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

editChange is being called from this onChange method

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost, UpdatePost,EditChange, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: ''
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })


    }


    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;

        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }

    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem
                             myTitle={this.state.title} 
                             editChange={this.onChange} 
                             editForm={this.formEditing} 
                             isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                             removePost={this.removePost} 
                             {...post} 
                        />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // disabled: state.post.disabled,
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**Action for this.props.DisableButton**

```
export const DisableButton = () => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type:DISABLED});
    }
}
```

**Posts reducer for disable button, etc.**

```
import { DISABLED} from '../actions/';

const initialState = {,
    disabled: false,
    isEditingId:null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case DISABLED:
            return({
                ...state,
                disabled:true
            })

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**editable component**

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const Editable = (props) => (
    <div>
        <TextField
            id="outlined-name"
            label="Title"
            style={{width: 560}}
            name="title"
            value={props.editField}
            onChange={props.editChange}
            margin="normal"
            required
            variant="outlined"/>

    </div>
)

export default Editable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `DisableButton` method to disable its value.

Fix your `onChange`, perhaps roughly like this:

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
}
```

yes, this is sufficient.

now you can use a logic to disable the `Button` component, like this:

```
<Button
  disabled={this.state.title.length <= 3}
  // rest of the attributes
/>
```

You don't need to use disabled props on redux. It's not necessary since you can just move the logic by using local state of `title` directly on `Button` component.

==== edit

you need to initialize this.state.title first

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    title: '',
  }

}
```

=== edit 2nd time after the questioner added some details

If `this.state.title` is on `PostList` (the parent component) component and your `Button` is accessing it through `myTitle` props since it's on `PostItem` component. You can do it like this:

```
<Button
  disabled={this.props.myTitle.length <= 3}
  // rest of the attributes
/>
```